# 'Not in' is not outputting expected values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I feel like an idiot asking this, but I have a main list and 2 lists that contain entries from the main list. I want to make a third list that contains the remaining entries in the main list. But for some reason, my for loop is just outputting every entry in the list, disregarding the if statement. Any idea why? This is my first time using a 1 liner for and if statement, but I tried doing it with regular syntax and it still didn't work.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn import preprocessing, linear_model, svm
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500) 
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

raw_df = pd.read_csv('parkinsons_updrs.data.txt', index_col=False)

#Check for missing data
#print(pd.isnull(raw_df).sum()) 

#Grouping the patients by subject #
ID = set(raw_df['subject#'])

df_mean = pd.DataFrame()

group = raw_df.groupby('subject#')

for patient, medical_data in group:
    #print(patient)
    #print(medical_data)
    df_mean = df_mean.append(medical_data.agg(np.mean), ignore_index=True)

jitter_col = [col for col in df_mean.columns.values if 'Jitter' in col]
shimmer_col = [col for col in df_mean.columns.values if 'Shimmer' in col]
remainder_col = [col for col in df_mean.columns.values if col not in jitter_col or col not in shimmer_col]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just change the last line to:

```
remainder_col = [col for col in df_mean.columns.values if col not in jitter_col and col not in shimmer_col]
```

In this way, the comprehension will filter `col` and return only the cases that are both not in `jitter_col` and `shimmer_col`.